# Can we raise the reputation required to chat, maybe on a per-room basis?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, chat

Another day in chat, another day of low rep people endlessly asking questions there, dumping their code, and generally behaving as if we're stackoverflow.com instead of chat.stackoverflow.com. Can we raise the barrier here a bit? It might stem the tides.

Edit: Per-room rep control would be fine- better, in fact.

Edit: Every time somebody dumps his question in the room, I'm going to dump a screenshot here. See how much you like it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would be better if room owners could set required rep for the room, in "room settings"

Comment: Are you getting the basic questions and the bikeshed questions?  Because chat is where we send people to ask those questions.  Which chat room are we talking about?

Comment: I mostly frequent the Lounge.

Comment: You've got pictures of pancakes and videos of people pulling boogers out of their nose in there.  I have no sympathy for you.

Comment: That stuff is supposed to be there.

Comment: Pictures of pancakes? What are we, savages? Waffles people, we need pictures of waffles!

Comment: @DeadMG No you don't, how can you even access the... oh, wait, you mean the _other_ Lounge... ;P

Comment: @RobertHarvey, right, because of that pancakes and template-esoteric stuff, we don't want to see people with 20 rep asking how to put a component on `TForm` -- it's just an off-topic there.

Comment: Our current work-around is just to aggressively bin everything. And in the extreme cases, we'll temporarily pull gallery mode. But being able to raise the rep-min in our room to something like 1k will mostly solve this problem. The explicit write-list will allow us to let anyone under the rep-min to talk.

Comment: Seriously, you'd think that all people do is sit in the chat rooms all day.  Oh, wait...

Comment: @Mysticial: Then you will be getting people asking in meta why they can't ask their basic and bikeshed questions in chat, when they've been *referred there* to ask such questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Believe it or not, bikeshed questions are rare in our room. And when they do happen, we tend welcome them. The real problems is people dumping links to their tumbleweed SO questions. In those cases, depending on the situation, we either ignore them and carry on, or we bin them if it becomes disruptive.

Comment: @Mysticial: Problem solved.

Comment: @casperOne That's kinda true actually, we recently had a room-owner shuffle to make sure we have all timezones covered. And that we always have at least one room owner in the room at all times. We had a few bad experiences of people spamming while no room owners were around.

Comment: Or, you know, give room owners more utility. (Incoming [meta-tag:status-declined] because it's not fair or something.)

Comment: **-1** for *Every time somebody dumps his question in the room, I'm going to dump a screenshot here. See how much you like it.* While this is a nice request and I approve as I said in my answer, part of your responsibility as a chat room owner is to keep the room on topic. Abusing MSO just to try and coerce the devs into building a feature for you is counterproductive and unlikely to work.

Comment: If any chat feature requests, ever, were actually implemented, maybe it wouldn't be necessary. Besides, it's hardly anything like that- two in five days is way less than the incident rate.

Comment: "part of your responsibility as a chat room owner" Ahahaha, what responsibility. The only tools for dealing with this we have is flagging (which *everybody* can do) and moving messages (which is cumbersome as hell, and ultimately doesn't stop anyone). Oh, right, and we can change topics. The most important thing ever.

Answer (score 29):

I don't approve of this request **if it would apply to *chat.stackexchange.com* as well**.

As a mod on [CogSci](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) I want *more* people in our chat, not less. I have found that chat can be helpful in cultivating new users and addressing quality issues. Furthermore, new users often ask *subjective* questions, for which chat is more appropriate than the main site.

Finally, chat can be very helpful in building new communities. We want more users in the chats for beta SE sites, not less.

So if this idea would apply to Stack Exchange chat as a whole, I strongly disagree.

**If this would be on a per-room basis, I might approve**. I'm not a fan of the lack of consistency, but I do like giving room owners more control.

Comment: Per-room would be fine for me.

Comment: Per-room might be complicated, and elitist, but I have no major objections :-)

Comment: In fact, per-room might be *better* because I could *lower* the rep requirements in The Axon Terminal!

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that C++ room is extremely popular :)

Comment: Several times I've tried helping new users with a question and the comments section was getting too long. We tried to move it to chat but were unable because their rep was too low. If anything the rep limit should be lower/controllable so room owners can chat with whomever they want.